# HTTP Status 404 - Project/registration.jsp

Tags: jsp, http-status-code-404

I have created a web project using **Servlet** and **JSP** but I am facing one issue with one of **JSP** that is **registration.jsp**.

I am using **eclipse** as **IDE**. I placed my JSP in Web content folder, not in any nested folder.

I am using below URL to run JSP.
`http://localhost:9090/ProjectName/registration.jsp`
but it's giving **Error - HTTP Status 404**

I configured as a welcome file list using below code

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
      <display-name>ProjectName</display-name>
      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>registration.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

After setting in the welcome file list. I am using below URL to test **JSP**

```
http://localhost:9090/ProjectName
```

It's running without error. I am looking for the reason why it's not working if we use manual URL.

Can someone assist me? What's actually wrong?? Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You mention that your jsp file is in your webcontent folder. Then your url will be implicit.

http://localhost:9090/ProjectName/registration.jsp

Does not work because that's not the correct url. "ProjectName is not needed because your folder webcontent is already in ProjectName.

So all you need is:

http://localhost:9090/registration.jsp

I also noticed your welcome file is set to registration.jsp. This means you can also access registration.jsp with only:

http://localhost:9090/

Comment: I already checked before posting question to stack. How is it possible to run without project name? ProjectName is not explicit value but it's my name of project.